# Is Wriggle’s Lantern worth getting on an AD carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

If so, in which situations is it good to buy a wriggles?

Answer (score 11):

I don't suggest you buy Wriggle's if you aren't having a problem sustaining in lane and you aren't going for aggressive Dragon/Baron control. For 1650 gold, you can get a best friend (BF) sword and gain 45 attack damage that can be built into better items.

A common start that gives many of the same stats as Wriggle's is two Doran's blades. 
For **950 gold**, you can get the common two Doran's blades:

- 6% Life Steal
- +20 Attack Damage
- +200 Health

These are generally enough if you are playing against an opponent that doesn't have a huge advantage during the laning phase, such as being a better laner, having a sustain support, or having more ganks from the jungle.

Generally I think it is stronger to build two Doran's blades into BF Sword into Infinity Edge (IE) for most AD carries. However, as well with most itemization questions it comes down to numerous other factors such as lane compositions, objective control, and relative experience of the players.

I also don't think it is a good investment if you are also planning to build Trinity Force. It is wiser to grab a Vampiric Scepter for lifesteal and rush a Phage for damage and health.

There are a couple of other comparable starts:

For **925 gold**, getting Vampiric Scepter and a Doran’s Blade will get you:

- 13% Life Steal
- +10 Attack Damage
- +100 Health

Vampiric Scepter also has the benefit of building into Bloodthirster, a common high end AD item. While, it is common for Wriggle's Lantern to be sold once you get 5 other top tier items.

For **1425 gold**, you can get three Doran's blades:

- 9% Life Steal
- +30 Attack Damage
- +300 Health

However, none of the Doran's will build into anything and will be sold as you run out of slots.

---

Of course, I don't mean to imply Wriggle's is a useless item. The important question to ask yourself when looking at Wriggle’s Lantern is: **Why do I need this?**

For **1600 gold** you get:

- +30 armor
- +23 attack damage
- 12% life steal
- Ward passive
- Minion killing passive

Wriggle’s ranks up there as one of the strongest items in the game in regards to trading damage with another AD champion. 
 - It gives you armor to reduce their damage.
 - It gives you attack damage to kill them faster.
 - It gives you life steal to sustain yourself throughout the fight

It also comes with the ability to ward every three minutes. This is equivalent to 4 gold every 10 seconds saved in ward buying costs. It also allows you to have a ward without having to give up a slot, one of the main limiting factors in warding.

Its passive allows you to easily take Dragon and Baron. If the jungler, AD carry, and top laner all build a Wriggle’s Lantern then it allows the team to make aggressive plays toward taking Dragon in the early game and Baron in the mid game.

Wriggle's shines early and mid game when it provides a good amount of armor, damage, life steal, and two very helpful passives. However, late game it is one of the first mid-game items to be sold as you build the standard: Infinity Edge, Last Whisper, Phantom Dancer AD build.

---

There are a few situations when you should prioritize a Wriggle’s Lantern:

**Your team is going to aggressively go after Dragon and Baron.** Wriggle’s Lantern will help you stay at good HP during the lane due to the life steal and armor, and when it comes time to take Dragon it will die quicker thanks to the Wriggle procs.

**You are being bullied in lane.** Another common time to think of Wriggle's Lantern is when you are being bullied during the laning phase by the opposing AD and support. If you don’t have a sustain support then you definitely need some sort of life steal during the laning phase. However, this situation does not neccessarily result in a clear cut win for Wriggle's Lantern.

**Source**: A lot of League of Legend games and watching a lot of Pro-streamers talk about it. Stats are from [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Items).

Comment: Good answer, but I hope by referring to BF Sword as "Best Friend Sword" you were joking ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes it still is the only nerf that I remember is the life steal % but it still give bonus armor.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on the match up. Normally if you're losing lane against the enemy AD, you build wriggles for the added armor and passive bonus. Now if the lanes are even, it's better worth it to go with additional doran's blades, vamp scepter, and start building infinity edge.

Answer (score 0):

It would only be good if you need some help farming faster, or if they are heavy ad.

Answer (score 0):

oh absolutely, the damage, lifesteal, armor and free ward every 5 minutes is extremely worth it. You cannot put a price on map awareness. especially unlimited wards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it you want any kind of sustain. It is still good for early/mid game but you of course loose damage but you get sustain to win your lane better.