# When is it a good idea to buy Wriggle's Lantern on ranged AD carries?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Wriggle’s Lantern worth getting on an AD carry?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58522/is-wriggles-lantern-worth-getting-on-an-ad-carry)

I've been told to never get it, to get it if my lane goes poorly, and to get it only when my lane goes well.  What's the deal?  Why so many differing opinions?  I just want to know the truth!

Answer (score 0):

You should only get it if you are behind, since it gives sustain, armor and attack damage to help you catch up on farm in lane. It also helps a bit with last hitting due to the extra damage to minions.

Another option is to get it if your team is trying some kind of fast drag/baron build where 2 or 3 members get one (top, jung and ad carry ussually).

PD: If you are ahead, you probably want to get the big items before your enemy like BF Sword to try and push that advantage, not a Wriggles Lantern.

Answer (score 0):

as someone who mains ad carries, i usually never go wriggles. there are 2 specific instances in which i would go wriggles and thats if im playing kog maw with a janna support since she has a damage amplifier with her shield and wriggles allows for more sustain + allows you to get your pd faster. the other situation is with miss fortune because her early base skills have high dmg and she can trade a lot better with the extra armor and sustain.